# Replace WordPress plugin icon using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, icons

I am trying to change a star rating icon in a WordPress plugin using PHP. I have done some research and found that the plugin has some hooks & filters to use:

Hook: wprm_recipe_rating_star_icon
Attribute: $icon
Description: What to use for the empty star rating icon

Hook: wprm_comment_rating_star_full_icon
Attribute: $icon
Description: What to use for the full star rating icon

I've tried with some basic PHP but it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing ??

```
// Inject custom star rating icon
add_filter( 'wprm_comment_rating_star_full_icon', 'custom_star_icon', 10, 1 );

function custom_star_icon() {
      $icon = 'http://example.com/mb.svg';
    return $icon;
}

add_filter( 'wprm_recipe_rating_star_icon', 'custom_empty_star_icon', 10, 1 );

function custom_empty_star_icon() {
   $icon = 'http://example.com/mb-empty.svg';
    return $icon;
}
```

It's giving me the following error:

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'custom_star_icon' not found or invalid function name in /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer myself. It was actually quite easy. I just had to echo out the SVG icon.

```
function recipe_custom_icon( $icon ) {
    $custom_icon = '<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/mb.svg" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 26px; height: auto; margin: 0;">';
    return $custom_icon;
}
add_filter( 'wprm_comment_rating_star_full_icon', 'recipe_custom_icon', 10, 1 );

function recipe_empty_custom_icon( $icon ) {
    $empty_custom_icon = '<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/m.svg" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 26px; height: auto; margin: 0;">';
    return $empty_custom_icon;
}
add_filter( 'wprm_recipe_rating_star_icon', 'recipe_empty_custom_icon', 10, 1 );
```